# Как создать метод для обратной сортировки от Z to A?

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace courses_5_task
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of game names you will specify");
            int NumberGame = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            string[] ArrGame = new string[NumberGame];

            Console.WriteLine($"Enter the {NumberGame} name of game:");
            for (int i = 0; i < ArrGame.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write($"Enter the {i+1} game - ");
                ArrGame[i] = Console.ReadLine();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Our games are:");
            for (int j = 0; j < ArrGame.Length; j++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ArrGame[j]);
            }
            
            GameSort(ArrGame);
            //Console.WriteLine(ArrGame);
        }

        static void GameSort(params string[] arr)
        {
            foreach (var item in arr)
            {
                Array.Reverse(arr);
                Console.WriteLine(arr);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: ну вообще можно в 1 строчку `ArrGame.OrderByDescending()`

Comment: `ArrGame = ArrGame.OrderByDescending(x => x).ToArray()` или `Array.Sort(ArrGame); Array.Reverse(ArrGame);`. Вывести массив в консоль `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, ArrGame));`

Answer (score 0):

По простому как-то так:

```
static void GameSort(string[] arr) 
{
    string temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length-1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.Length; j++)
        {
            if (arr[i] < arr[j])
            {
                temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr;
            }
        }
    }
}
```